# How To Disable certain days in the date picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was trying to disable certain days in the date picker like Friday is off so I need to disble friday from the date picker

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?  .... [this might help you](http://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/gj90f1bm/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code  **to disable friday** from the date picker

```js
function DisableFriday(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
     if (day == 5) {
     return [false,"","Unavailable"] ; 
     } else { 
     return [true] ;
     } 
    }
    jQuery(function($){
        $('input[name="chk_date"]').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', DisableFriday).datepicker('refresh');
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" name="chk_date" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
```